# Angular2 - Symfony3 app how to send session between client and server?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, rest, symfony

I'm building a web app using Angular2 for the client side and Symfony3 for the server like as a kind of REST API. 
But I don't find how I could share the user's session ID between Angular and Symfony.

I tried storing the session in Symfony but the session is not staying and it seems not to be following the REST rules.

I then tried to store the session in Angular as a localStorage, but ran into the following problem : 
How to tell to Symfony about this session ? The only solution a found was to send this session in the link as a GET parameter, but I don't like this. I see it like a security fault and it would also be quite heavy always adding the Session Id in every routes...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into JSON Web Tokens (https://jwt.io) as a better alternative to cookies (in cases like yours).

If you still want to use cookies, you can always set the cookie at the start of the session from Symfony, and that will get sent for each request to the server.

You'll have to deal with session id regeneration yourself though.

Comment: that sounds great thanks, I'll take a look at that !

Answer (score 1):

As Magd mentioned, you can use JWT.

Basically, the JSON web token (JWT) is nothing more than a big JSON string that contains whatever data you want to put into it – like a user’s id or their favorite color. But then, the JSON is cryptographically signed and encoded to create a new string that doesn’t look like JSON at all.

For example, a user enters his credentials in your Angular login form. That data is sent to REST API. And if the credentials are valid, REST API returns JWT. The Angular app (client) stores token in local storage and sends it for authentication on every request.

To create your token authentication system, you can use Guard – part of Symfony’s core security system.

More info you can find out at:
http://matkodjipalo.com/index.php/2016/08/18/symfony-rest-api-token-authentication/

or:
https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/symfony-rest4/json-web-token#play

Also, you should use HTTPS.

Comment: that sounds great thanks, I'll take a look at that !